# Set Operations Proof Confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working through a problem that is asking for a proof of $$A-(A\cap B^c) = A \cap B$$ without using any theorems. I don't know where to start without using a theorem, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show every element of the left hand side is also in the right hand side, and vice versa.

Comment: Maybe start with $A\cap B^c=A-B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should argue by pure logic:

$A\cap B^c$ is the set of elements in $A$ that are also in the complment of $B$. If we take them away from $A$, as the left side is doing,then we are left with only elements that are in $A$ and not in the complement of $B$. In other words, they are in both $A$ and $B$, as the right sides states.

Comment: This does not show equality. It shows the left hand side is contained in the right hand side.

Comment: This is not a double-inclusion argument. It is inherently biconditional. Read it carefully.